# iphone learn to design and create own GUI

Tags: iphone, user-interface

I want to know what is good start point to work on creating own GUI on iphone/objective-c. I've never done this part before, and I know I'm kinda attracted to make my own slick GUI, something like convertbot, which I really love :)

Any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the [Design Then Code](http://designthencode.com/) tutorials written by Mike Rundle. I've heard good things about them.

Also, [Tapworthy](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920001133) is a good read for those wanting to learn about designing interfaces for iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

[Interface builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) is quite powerful to build UI. However you could start creating custom views in objective-c and that would mean learing how to write code in objective-c.

Answer (score 1):

To be a little more complete, you could have included Fireworks among the apps that can be used to design for iPhone. I hope you won’t mind me plugging it here :)

Adobe Fireworks (http://www.adobe.com/fireworks) is also an excellent application for designing and prototyping for the iPhone. With this vector toolkit from MetaSpark (http://blog.metaspark.com/2009/02/fireworks-toolkit-for-creating-iphone-ui-mockups/), you can use the iPhone interface elements in Fireworks to quickly create prototypes. Fireworks has a nice feature called Pages, that allows designing each of the screens of your iPhone app. Then you can use the Hotspots feature to link buttons to the various Pages/screens in your app. Very quick and easy.

Luke Kilpatrick shows Robert Scoble how this is done in this video: http://www.building43.com/videos/2009/06/23/mockup-iphone-app-adobe-fireworks/

When your design is complete, you have several options for sharing it with clients and other stakeholders:
+ Export to PDF from Fireworks, which you can send to clients to review using the commenting features in the PDF
+ Export to HTML and Images from Fireworks to view your prototype in the Browser
+ Export to AIR from Fireworks to create an AIR prototype
+ Export to HTML and a Dreamweaver Library from Fireworks and use this jQuery trick (http://unitid.nl/2009/04/prototyping-for-the-iphone-using-fireworks-cs3/) to get the app running on your iPhone without learning Objective C. The jQuery hides the Safari Chrome so it looks and feels like a native app, but ti is running in the Safari browser on the iPhone.
+ Use jQTouch (http://www.jqtouch.com/) which uses a similar method to the above

I’m hearing of people using Fireworks to design and prototype for all kinds of mobile devices such as the ,iPhone 4, [iPhone 4 Cases](http://saraoutlet.com/iphone-4-cases-iphone4case.html), Palm webOS (Pre and Pixi), BlackBerry, Symbian, Windows Mobile, etc. In fact, people use it for other screen design too, set-top boxes like the TiVo, PS3, Xbox, interactive kiosks, proprietary medical devices, in car interface screens – really any device with a screen.

Thanks!
Pat Siregar

Answer (score -1):

Read Apple's Human Interface Guidelines:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

There is a lot of useful information there about how to design good UI's.

Once you are familiar and have practiced the things mentioned there, then you can think about designing more complex UI elements.